# Why is my class not found in Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x

I have two two Classes in separate files in the same directory both with the same namespace and yet when one Class requests the other Class it is not found. The only way I have been able to get this to work is to use a `require_once` which is not how I think it should be and I am going around in circles trying to find the cause and I think I am missing something simple.

**administrator/components/com_inventorydata/src/Model/ItemsModel.php**

```
namespace Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model;

...
use Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model\Inventory;
class ItemsModel extends ListModel
...
    public function getRecords()
    {
        require_once('Inventory.php');     //Shouldn't be required.
        $records    = new Inventory();     //Unable to find this class.
        $test       = $records->query;
    }
```

**administrator/components/com_inventorydata/src/Model/Inventory.php**

```
namespace Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model;
...
class Inventory 
{
...
}
```

The IDE(PHPStorm) indicates that `use Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model\Inventory;` in `ItemsModel.php` is not required and is greyed out.

Without the `require_once` statement before trying to instantiate Inventory() in `ItemsModel.php` I get a Class not found message.
[image]

I have stepped through the processing watching it try to find the class of Inventory and it eventually returns a `false` and adds it to the missingClasses properties.

In the debug what I see looks okay to me, but then this is the first time I have had to look closely at this area of code so what do I know.

```
$class = "Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model\Inventory"
$ext = ".php"
$first = "B"
$lastPos = false
$logicalPathPsr0 = "Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model\Inventory.php"
$logicalPathPsr4 = "Bricks\Component\Inventorydata\Administrator\Model\Inventory.php"
```

Not that I think it is related but the components folder is a `symlink` to my development directories.

Any assistance appreciated.

Update 8 Sept.
**From manifest**

```
<namespace path="src">Bricks\Component\InventoryData</namespace>
```

Comment: First question - have you set up the namespace path in your manifest xml?

E.g. <namespace path="src/">Bricks\Component\Inventorydata</namespace>

Comment: @GrantHood yes, I have updated the original post with the namespace element from the manifest.xml. It is a very basic admin component at this stage that works in so much it displays a list of records so I am happy that the Namespace is okay.

Comment: So is your base namespace `Bricks\Component\Inventorydata` or `Bricks\Component\InventoryData`? Casing matters.

Comment: @sharky Thank you, that was the cause the difference in InventoryData and Inventorydata. If you would like to post that as your answer I will mark it as closed. I can't see the wood for the trees some days. I found it different in two places, just enough for the class to be not found.